# List of Nuget packages for migrating database to PostgreSQL with Entity Framework Core

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core

I am creating a project with **Entity Framework Core** with the **code first** approach. I want to migrate the database to the **PostgreSQL** database. Now I wonder which **Nuget packages** should I install to my project? I guess the below NuGet packages are needed.

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL
EFCore.NamingConventions
```

Now my question is should I install all the above NuGet Packages or should I only install **Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL** ? Can anyone give me some details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially all you need is: Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL as it depends on several of the other packages.